# Download data via a ftp server using polygon features

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, download, ftp

The attached script loops through the features of a polygon featureclass and uses that attribute information to download particular files via a ftp server.  The script works great for downloading files as long as all of the files on the ftp server are contained within one folder ([example](ftp://ftp.agrc.utah.gov/Imagery/NAIP2011_4-band/)).

Now, I need to download imagery via a ftp server with a different file structure ([example](ftp://atlas.ca.gov/pub/naip/2012/doqqs_combined_color-nir/)) where files are contained within multiple folders.  How can I tweak the code so that the following actions occur?:

1. Use polygon features to identify the necessary file to download (completed)
2. Access the correct folder and download the imagery

I suspect that I need to utilize the [os.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module, however, I cannot seem to put the pieces together.

---

```
# Download data via a ftp server

import arcpy, ftplib, os, socket

HOST = 'ftp.agrc.utah.gov'
DIRN = '/Imagery/NAIP2011_4-band/'
#FILE = ''     # Defined later in for loop
workspace = r'F:\my\workspace'  # This is where the downloads go
quads = r'F:\path\to\polygon\shapefile' # Used to define which files to download

# Get current working directory
print 'The current working directory is %s' % os.getcwd()

# Change the current working directory to a download folder
os.chdir(workspace)
print 'The workspace has been changed to %s' % workspace 

try:
    f = ftplib.FTP(HOST)
except (socket.error, socket.gaierror), e:
    print 'ERROR: cannot reach "%s"' % HOST
print '*** Connected to host "%s"' % HOST

try:     
    f.login()
except ftplib.error_perm:
    print 'Error: cannot login anonymously'
    f.quit()
print '*** Logged in as "anonymous"'

try:
    f.cwd(DIRN)
except ftplib.error_perm:
    print 'ERROR: cannot CD to "%s"' % DIRN
    f.quit()
print '*** Changed to "%s" folder' % DIRN

# Use search cursor to loop through download polygons,
# get the name of the required file and use that name to download file on ftp site
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(quads, ("TILE_NAME", "QUADID")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row[0]
        FILE = row[0] + ".tif"
        name = row[1]

        try:
            f.retrbinary('RETR %s' % FILE, open(FILE, 'wb').write)
            arcpy.Rename_management(os.path.join(workspace, FILE), os.path.join(workspace, name + ".tif"))
        except ftplib.error_perm:
            print 'ERROR: cannot read file "%s"' % FILE
            os.unlink(FILE)
        else:
            print '*** Downloaded "%s" to CWD' % FILE
f.quit()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example you have a root folder containing many numbered folders.

Can you simply:

1) Use python to list the numbered folders:

```
    files = ftp.dir()
    print files
```

2) Match your polygon feature to the correct folder

3) Open the correct directory

```
ftp.cwd("/numbered_folder")
```

4) Use your existing code to download the files.

Comment: Thanks for the help Radar.  The specific implementation is included below.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is a two-liner:

Add a folder name from the polygon attribute table

```
folder = row[0][:5] + "/"
```

And then change the directory within every iteration

```
f.cwd(DIRN + folder)
```

To put it all together starting with the `with` statement:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(quads, ("TILE_NAME", "QUADID")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row[0]
        FILE = row[0] + ".tif"
        name = row[1]
        folder = row[0][:5] + "/"

        try:
            f.cwd(DIRN + folder)
            f.retrbinary('RETR %s' % FILE, open(FILE, 'wb').write)
            arcpy.Rename_management(os.path.join(workspace, FILE), os.path.join(workspace, name + ".tif"))
        except ftplib.error_perm:
            print 'ERROR: cannot read file "%s"' % FILE
            os.unlink(FILE)
        else:
            print '*** Downloaded "%s" to CWD' % FILE
```